# how to fetch the "add_loc" string from dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

how to fetch the "add_loc" string in variable from dictionary of dictionary in python. I need to compare the variable.

**Example**

```
{
  "changes": [
    {
      "add_loc": {
        "props": {
          "AWS_IAM_Role": "some-value"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "add_changes": {
        "props": {
          "Agent_Port": 4343
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `df['run_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['run_time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: It is not working in VS code... throwing error "Couldn't find the strftime file"

Comment: df['run_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['run_time'])
df['run_time'] = df['run_time'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: tried this but didn't work

Comment: Then your question lacks details, please [edit] it to provide the exact error and full traceback (not a description of it)

Comment: When the execution to the step "df['run_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['run_time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" ... It is throws the error in VS "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found."

Comment: As requested, please [edit] the question and **provide the full code and the full error traceback**, not just the error message. Most likely your error had nothing to do with the date conversion.